# Visual Studio App Center: missing .csproj files

Tags: xamarin.forms, continuous-deployment, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to configure automatic build of a **Xamarin Forms** application, for **Android** and **iOS**, using **Visual Studio App Center**, but after choosing the branch in Build App\Project select box I cannot see my projects (**.csproj** files). Or better, I'm not able to see the .csproj files of projects I have to build (customers' customizations), but I can see the .csproj of my core projects.

Configuring iOS build I was able to select the .sln file, and it worked, but on Android I cannot see neither the .csproj nor the .sln.

My repository structure:

- root folder

  - src
  - main solution file
  - Core projects
  - customers' customizations folder

    - customer A folder
    - customer A .sln
    - customer A iOS, Android and Forms folders, each one with a .csproj file
  - ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of blasphemies I've found the reason here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/xamarin/android/

> For best performance, the analysis is currently limited to **four**
>   **directory levels** including the root of your repository.

My repository was too deep and .csproj files weren't reachable. I contacted Microsoft to ask if I had to change my repository structure and they said that yes, the only solution to quick solve was to remove a "layer", so I deleted the src folder moving all the content at the top level.

Comment: This strikes me every so much months :)

Comment: @Hutjepower I write answers on StackOverflow so when I forget I can find them here, like this one for example :)